# Removing Outer Brackets

Tags: list-manipulation

I am getting this:  {{{{{{1, 1}}, {2, 4}}, {3, 9}}, {4, 16}}, {5, 25}}

I want it like this:  {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}}   so that I can use this as coordinate points in ListPlot to make a plot.

I tried using Flatten (it removes all the inner brackets so that it stops being a coordinate) , First etc but nothing worked. Please help

Comment: Thank you. As of now, using cvgmt's method works perfectly fine. I will check the link out, nonetheless.

Comment: A simple method is to `Flatten` as you suggested but then to `Partition` into sublists of 2. This should work:   `Partition[Flatten[list],2]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
list= {{{{{{1, 1}}, {2, 4}}, {3, 9}}, {4, 16}}, {5, 25}};
Level[list, {-2}]
```

We can using `TreeForm` to understand the method.

```
list= {{{{{{1, 1}}, {2, 4}}, {3, 9}}, {4, 16}}, {5, 25}};
TreeForm[list]
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note that while this code solves this particular problem, it is not a general solution, since it only works for atomic list elements (numbers in this case).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin  Thank you,I will go to  learn the new method which the link provide.